# Prove a simple property of summation

Tags: summation

I've come across the following fact many times, and I used to take it for granted. However, I cannot think of a both beautiful and rigorous proof of it:

> **Fact 1**:For two non-empty finite sets $A,B$ and map $f:A\times B\to \mathbb R,$ 
>   If we have 
>   $\big[\exists x_1\neq x_2\in A\times B,\ s.t. f(x_1)=f(x_2)=X\big]\Longrightarrow X=0,$
>
> then we have $\displaystyle\sum_{x\in A}\sum_{y\in B} f(x,y)=\sum_{z\in f(A\times B)} z.$

**Question:** I know that we can prove this fact using induction, but is there some more beautiful proof of this fact? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I find that this fact also holds when $A,B$ are at most countable sets, and $f\geqslant 0.$

**Update:** Fact 1 is just a special case of the following fact:

> **Fact 2:** For non-empty finite set $A$ and map $A\to \mathbb R,$ if we have 
>   $\big[\exists x_1,x_2\in A,\ s.t. f(x_1)=f(x_2)=X\big]\Longrightarrow X=0,$
>   then we have $\displaystyle\sum_{x\in A} f(x)=\sum_{z\in f(A)} z.$

---

> **Proof:** According to @Christian Blatter's answer, we have$$\displaystyle\sum_{x\in A} f(x)=\sum_{z\in f(A)-\left\{0\right\}} \mathrm{Card}\big(f^{-1}(z)\big)z,$$   here $f^{-1}(z):=\left\{x\in A|\ f(x)=z\right\}.$  
>    According to the assumption of fact 2, we have $\mathrm{Card}\big(f^{-1}(z)\big)=1$ for each $z\in f(A)-\left\{0\right\}.$ Thus we have$$\displaystyle\sum_{x\in A} f(x)=\sum_{z\in f(A)-\left\{0\right\}} z=\sum_{z\in f(A)} z.$$**End of Proof**

---

In addition, the following  fact could be proved similarly:

> **Fact 3:** For two non-empty finite sets $A, B$ and map $\sigma:A\to B,\ \psi:B\to \mathbb R,$ let $f=\psi\circ \sigma,$ denote the set of all zeros of a real-valued function $g$ as $\mathrm{Kel}(g),$ and the image set of a real-valued function $g$ as $\mathrm{Im}(g),$ then
>
> a) if we have 
>   $\big[\exists x_1,x_2\in A,\ s.t. \sigma(x_1)=\sigma(x_2)=X\big]\Longrightarrow X\in \mathrm{Kel}(\psi),$
>   then we have $$\displaystyle\sum_{x\in A} f(x)=\sum_{z\in \mathrm{Im}(\sigma)} \psi(z).$$
>   b) if we have 
>   $\big[\exists x_1,x_2\in B,\ s.t. \psi(x_1)=\psi(x_2)=X\big]\Longrightarrow X=0,$ and $\sigma$ is injective,
>   then we have $$\displaystyle\sum_{x\in A} f(x)=\sum_{z\in \psi\big(\mathrm{Im}(\sigma)\big)} z=\sum_{z\in \mathrm{Im}f} z.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the "beauty" of a proof is subjective to a certain degree, I still post my answer using [elementary-set-theory](/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory).

It suffices to establish a bijection between the support of $f:A \times B \to \Bbb{R}$ (part of the domain which gives nonzero function value) and the *nonzero* image $f(A\times B)\setminus\{0\}$.  (We ignore the terms $z=f(x,y)=0$, which have *no* contribution to the sums.)
$$\text{supp}(f):=\{(x,y)\in A\times B \mid f(x,y)\ne0\} \leftrightarrow
\{z \in f(A \times B) \mid z \ne 0\}=f(A\times B)\setminus\{0\}$$

Rewrite the set on the RHS as $\{f(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}\mid x \in A, y \in B, f(x,y)\ne0\}$.  Obviously, the bijection *to be constructed* is $\tilde{f}:\text{supp}(f) \to f(A\times B)\setminus\{0\}$.  By abuse of notation, we'll denote $\tilde{f}$ (defined on the *support* of $f$) as $f$.

- surjectivity is guaranteed by the very definition of the set on the RHS
- injectivity is *assumed*: if there are two different elements $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in \text{supp}(f)$ giving the same function value $f(x_1,y_1) = f(x_2,y_2)$, then the assumption in the question implies $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)=0$, which contradicts the very definition of $\text{supp}(f)$.

Since the sets $A$ and $B$ are finite, so as their direct product $A \times B$.  Finally we have
$$\sum_{(x,y)\in \text{supp}(f)} f(x,y) = \sum_{z\in f(A\times B)\setminus\{0\}} z,$$
which is equivalent to the desired equality.

Comment: Your proof is correct, but it still takes me quite a long time to figure out why it works...

Comment: @painday Proving indices are pointing to the *same* objects is a word game if you don't find this obvious.  We emphasized that $A \times B$ is *finite* since in infinite case, bijection between indices doesn't mean pointing to the same terms (think of a sum over integers and over *even* integers).

Comment: Right, and I think the key point of the proof is that $\tilde f:\mathrm{supp }f\to f(A\times B)-\left\{0\right\}$ is a bijection. I really like the idea of "support of a function".

Comment: @painday When I wrote this, I had a much simpler sentence in mind: "cut off the zero and get a bijection".  I start developing the habit of writing sentences after reading some pages from Paul Halmos' autobiography *I wanna be a mathematician*.  Btw, I found the equation in the alternative solution presents the idea of "number of elements" clearer than mine.

Comment: Now I find that the fact that "there is a bijection between $\mathrm{supp}f$ and $f(A\times B)-\left\{0\right\}$" is somehow useless in the proof. We only need the fact that "$\tilde f:\mathrm{supp}f\to f(A\times B)-\left\{0\right\}$ is a bijection, and $\tilde f$ is exactly the restriction of $f$" .

Comment: Yeah, the cardinal number is  a very clear concept. But that method could not be extended to the infinite condition, while your proof could be extended  to the positive term series.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ and $B$ are finite the set $R:=f(A\times B)\subset{\mathbb R}$ is finite as well. It is then obvious that
$$\sum_{(x,y)\in A\times B} f(x,y)=\sum_{z\in R}\bigl|f^{-1}(\{z\})\bigr|\>z=\sum_{z\in R}z\ ,$$
as $\bigl|f^{-1}(\{z\})\bigr|=1$ for all $z\in R\setminus\{0\}$, by assumption.

(Here $\bigl|f^{-1}(\{z\})\bigr|$ denotes the number of pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying $f(x,y)=z$.)

Comment: $\bigl|f^{-1}(\{0\})\bigr|$ can be greater than $1$, this doesn't affect the sum though.

Comment: @GNUSupporter: Thank you for spotting and reporting my blunder.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the fact into infinite condition, we assume that at least one of  $A,B$ is countable set, and $f\geqslant 0.$

According to the answer by @GUN Supporter, we can prove that 
$\widetilde f:\mathrm{supp}f\to f(A\times B)-\left\{0\right\},\ t\mapsto f(t)$ is bijective, thus for any bijection $\sigma:\mathbb N\to \mathrm{supp} f,$ and any bijection $\tau:\mathbb N\to f(A\times B)-\left\{0\right\},$ just let $\psi=\tau^{-1}\circ \tilde f\circ \sigma,$ then $\psi$ is a bijection, and we have
$$\tilde f\circ \sigma=\tau\circ \psi.$$
Recall the fact that we can change the order of the terms of a positive series freely without affecting its convergence, now we have 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \big(\tilde f\circ \sigma\big)(i)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\big(\tau\circ \psi\big)(i)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\tau(i),$$ for any bijection $\sigma,\tau.$ Now we obtain that
$$\sum_{(x,y)\in \mathrm{supp}f}f(x,y)=\sum_{z\in f(A\times B)-\left\{0\right\}} z,$$
or
$$\sum_{x\in A}\sum_{y\in B} f(x,y)=\sum_{z\in f(A\times B)} z.$$